# Practical way to load from chrome.storage.local.get

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, browser-extension

I am trying to make a javascript method to load multiple simple settings from the browser local storage.

Currently I have the following code which work, but it quickly get unpractical and lengthy to load multiple settings ( I only provided 2 for this example ):

```
const readLocalStorage = async (key) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  chrome.storage.local.get([key], function (result) {
    if (result[key] === undefined) {
      reject();
    } else {
      resolve(result[key]);
    }
  });
});
};

function somefunction(){
    await readLocalStorage('settingsSelfDiscard')
        .then(function(result) {
            if(result == true || result == false){
                selfDiscard = result;
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            //Can't retreive the key, probably non-existent
        });

    await readLocalStorage('settingsCompactToolbar')
        .then(function(result) {
            if(result == true || result == false){
                compactToolbar = result;
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            //Can't retreive the key, probably non-existent
        });
}
```

I would like a method which I can use like, or similar to this:

```
selfDiscard = loadLocalStorage("settingsSelfDiscard");
compactToolbar = loadLocalStorage("settingsCompactToolbar");
```

And just get null if it's non-existent.

Comment: Why are you passing single key to `readLocalStorage` function? How about passing multiple keys and extracting them at once from `localStorage`?If this helps you I can share this approach

Comment: Honestly, this is a case of copy and pasting a bunch of code I don't understand and I found something that work but it not elegant for my purpose. Hence my question. Yes, retrieving multiple keys at once would be great !

Answer (score 1):

Since the API is asynchronous you can't use it without `await` or `then`, but you can get multiple keys in one call by providing an array to `get`, see [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/storage#method-StorageArea-get). BTW in ManifestV3 the API is already promisified:

```js
let {foo, bar} = await chrome.storage.local.get(['foo', 'bar']);
```

Comment: foo and bar return an object encapsulating of the content, and not the content.

Comment: I had success with: 
data  = await chrome.storage.local.get(['settingsThreshold','settingsSelfDiscard']);
 consensusThreshold = data.settingsThreshold;
 selfDiscard = data.settingsSelfDiscard;

Comment: Of course, this is how destructuring works. To use it with an already declared variable you must do it inside an expression: `({foo: var1, bar: var2} = await chrome.storage.local.get(['foo', 'bar']))`